# Button with link inside Bootstrap accordion table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap accordion table that works perfectly. Basically, it shows more content if someone clicks a row. Now, the problem is that one of the rows contains a button link and when someone clicks that button, it goes to that link correctly, but it also opens the hidden row content.

How do I make it so that when someone clicks on the button, it doesn't open the hidden row as well and goes to the link only?

```
<table class="table">

<thead>

<th width="20%" class="">Row 1</th>
<th width="20%" class="">Row 2</th>
<th width="20%" class="">Row 3</th>
<th width="20%" class="">Row 4</th>
<th width="20%" class="">Row 5</th>

</thead>

<tbody>

<tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#123" class="accordion-toggle">

<td class="">Content 1</td>
<td class="">Content 2</td>
<td class="">Content 3</td>
<td class="">Content 4</td>
<td class=""><a href="http://www.url.com/" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Link</a></td>
</tr><tr>
<td colspan="5" class="hiddenRow"><div class="accordian-body collapse" id="123">More Content</div> </td>
</tr>

</tbody>

</table>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:-

```
<a href="http://www.url.com/" onclick= stopEventPropogation(event) type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Link</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function stopEventPropogation(e){
e.stopPropogation()
}
</script>
```

OR as suggested by Bart this can also be used:-

```
$('.accordion-toggole').on('click', '.btn', function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); })
```

Comment: you can also do unobstrusive `$('.accordion-toggole').on('click', '.btn', function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); })` add it to your answer if you feel like it.

Comment: typo, - propogation should be propagation